# show timezone - PostgreSQL 11 - different value depending on client?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rds

Postgres 11

`show timezone;`

This gives me different values
- when I run it from DBeaver (shows America/New_York) vs.
- when I run it from PG Admin (shows UTC)

I run DBeaver and PG Admin from the same client machine.

I thought this was supposed to show me the server timezone.

Same for `clock_timestamp()` - I get different values.

Is this somehow related to the client OS timezone?
Or to some connection settings?

We're using an AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance which
is configured (as I checked) in UTC timezone.

What is the explanation?
I am really puzzled.

Comment: "*I thought this was supposed to show me the server timezone*" - No, it's the session timezone, not the server timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timezone` is the timezone of the database session, not of the server.

It looks like DBeaver sets the parameter, while pgAdmin leaves it at its default value (whatever is configured on the server).

You can set the `PGTZ` environment variable to specify your desired PostgreSQL database session time zone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But why is this affecting even the behavior of table `timestamp` columns which have a default value set to `clock_timestamp()`. When I do an INSERT, the value of the default column depends on the timezone of the session which inserted the record. I get one value from DBeaver and another from PG Admin. I always thought default columns are assigned values by the DB and so your session timezone should not matter. I though this `clock_timestamp()` call is executed on the server.

Comment: I posted this as a separate question in order to explain better what I am doing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62218271/postgresql-11-default-timestamp-column