# PostgreSQL 11 - default timestamp column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this.

```
create table public.test123
(id int not null primary key, dt timestamp null default clock_timestamp());
```

I then insert into it from 2 different client sessions, the first session is from PG Admin, the second one is from DBeaver.

1. In the first session when I run `show timezone;` it returns `UTC`.
   So this session's timezone is `UTC`. So from this session I do an insert as follows.

   ```
    insert into public.test123(id) values (1);
   ```
2. In the second session I have timezone `America/New_York` and I do this.

   ```
    insert into public.test123(id) values (2);
   ```

I run the two inserts just a few seconds apart from each other.

But I get two very different values in the DB e.g.

```
    id|dt                 |
    --|-------------------|
     1|2020-06-05 14:38:18|
     2|2020-06-05 10:38:26|
```

I always thought that in such scenario the `clock_timestamp()` call is executed on the server, and the timezone of the client session should not matter. And I expected to get two values which are a few seconds apart, and not 4 hours apart.

What am I missing?

And also, is there any way to get a timestamp independent of the client session's timezone?

How can I create a column with default timestamp values which are really independent on the client session's timezone?

Comment: Seems the solution is to create the column as `timestamp with time zone`. I am not sure I quite get it, but this seems to work fine for my use case. By default `timestamp` means `timestamp without time zone`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl;dr: Switch to timestamptz.

---

I'll refer to the `timestamp` types by their short names: `timestamp without time zone` is `timestamp` and `timestamp with time zone` is `timestamptz`.

Both `timestamp` and `timestamptz` store an absolute point in time. `timestamp with time zone` also records the time zone it was entered in.

For example, `2020-06-05 20:22:48Z` and `2020-06-05 13:22:48-0700` both represent the same moment in time, but the first is in Universal Coordinated Time and the other is 7 hours offset (Pacific Daylight Time).

`timestamptz` will store `2020-06-05 13:22:48-0700` as `2020-06-05 20:22:48`, the absolute point in time, but also remember that it was entered with 7 hours offset. When you retrieve it you'll get `2020-06-05 13:22:48-0700` which is the same time as `2020-06-05 20:22:48Z`.

`timestamp` will ignore the time zone completely. It stores `2020-06-05 13:22:48-0700` as `2020-06-05 13:22:48`, no time zone, no conversion, and that's it.

---

On to the specific problem: `dt timestamp null default clock_timestamp()`

`clock_timestamp()` returns `timestamptz`, but you're storing it in a `timestamp`. Postgres will cast one to the other by simply dropping the time zone. It will not convert it. If the time zone is in UTC and it's `2020-06-05 20:22:48Z` it will store `2020-06-05 20:22:48`. If the time zone is in America/New York and it's `2020-06-05 16:22:48-0400` it will store `2020-06-05 16:22:48`.

> And also... is there any way to get a timestamp independent of the client session's timezone?

They are all independent of the client's time zone, it's the type conversion that's a problem. Switch to `timestamptz`.

---

[Time zones are complicated](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES), but here's two strategies to deal with them when moving timestamps in and out of the database.

1. Use `timestamp` and *always* work in UTC.
2. Use `timestamptz` and *always* include a time zone.

The former is simpler, and [many frameworks take this approach](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones). But I prefer the latter because, as complex and infuriating as they are, people like the time to be vaguely in sync with the Sun.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it. I suspected it's something like this. I just needed someone to clarify it explicitly and in some details. Thanks.

Comment: So timezone and timezonetz - internally they don't store the number of milliseconds since the epoch. Right? If they did... then both datatypes would work in my use case, I think. So internally they just store date value and time value (and timezonetz also stores the tz), is that understanding correct?

Comment: @peter.petrov No. Both `timezone` and `timezonetz` ***do*** store *microseconds* since an epoch (not 1970). `timezonetz` also stores the time zone. The time zone only affects how the timestamp is presented. See [8.5. Date/Time Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) and [8.5.3 Time Zones](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES).

Comment: But if they do, then why the client session timezone matters? The number of millis/micros since the epoch is (almost) the same in my two inserts. Then when I read the two in NY timezone why do I see values different by 4 hours? By epoch I mean that moment of time "00:00 UTC 1/1/1970".

Comment: @peter.petrov Because while both store as microseconds since an epoch (again, not 1970), the type casting works by the date and time. For example: `select clock_timestamp();` is `2020-06-05 13:44:57.553102-07`. But `select clock_timestamp()::timestamp;` is `2020-06-05 13:44:57.553102`. The type casting uses the same date and time ignoring the time zone.

Comment: Aha... yeah, that's what I mean. But at the end of the day, the number of micros stored is significantly different in my two records, right? It gets messed up during that implicit casting from timestamptz to timestamp. Because that casting goes through the date/time values, not through the number of micros. Correct?

Comment: @peter.petrov Yes. *8.5.1.3. Time Stamps* lays it out. "*In a literal that has been determined to be timestamp without time zone, PostgreSQL will silently ignore any time zone indication. That is, the resulting value is derived from the date/time fields in the input value, and is not adjusted for time zone.*"

Comment: Thanks very much. I think I get it much better now. Previously I was just vaguely suspecting something like that :)

Comment: Thanks, I need timezone for dates, but it doesn't seem that they are stored, it most likely convert dates to my local timezone, which is not what we would want in an international application: `create table test2(
   a timestamptz
);
insert into test2 values ('2014-08-23 08:50:57.136817 America/New_York');
select a from test2; -- displays 2014-08-23 14:50:57.136 +0200`

Comment: @pdem Yes, timestamptz does not store the time zone (it's a misleading name, but that's the SQL standard). It uses the time zone to convert to UTC and stores that. When you retrieve it, it converts to your local time zone. If you want to retain the time zone, you need to store it and apply it yourself. timestamps are always stored as UTC.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `timestamp with time zone`, which is an absolute timestamp, would be the correct data type in your case.

If you use `timestamp without time zone`, the result of `clock_timestamp()`, which is a `timestamp with time zone`, is converted (cast implicitly) to a `timestamp without time zone` according to the current setting of `timezone`.